# Analyzing Multiple time series data with multiple levels on python

Tags: python, time, aggregation, series

I am trying to work out the best approach to solving a problem I am working on. I have data with 11 separate months of data collected simultaneously with 5 min intervals with  5 variables. so in each collection, or each month, I have data from 50 different buildings and some have multiple floors some don't. so the header looks something like:

```
        d = {'time': [2018,2018,2017], 'Usage': [45,84,17], 'Location': ['City', 
    'School', 'Hospital'], 'BuildingName': ['cafe','Darwin', 'Library'], 
    'Floor':['A', 'B', 'F']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    df
```

I am working with python. Is it possible to create 1 time series of each building for the whole 11 months. Is aggregating the data advisable in this scenario? I am  worried that this could lead to inaccurate results 
My goal is to analyze this and model the customer behavior

Comment: What is expected output? Is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I expect to end up with 1 time series for, say the cafe for the entire year and all the rest of the buldings.